# Javascript, a cross platform way for handle resize Event ONLY it occurs

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, cross-platform

I want execute a function when the size of the current windows has changed.

I have this very simple code : (foo.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
    <script>
      function resize() {alert("FOO");}
      window.onresize = resize;
    </script>
</html>
```

On Firefox Quantum v60.4 (Desktop), this code works like a charm. When I resize the firefox window, the alert is showed. And when I only load the page "foo.html" the alert "FOO" does not appears.

But :

- On Chrome v71.0.3578 (Desktop), when I resize the window the alert appears twice.
- Worst, On my Android smartphone (with Firefox v67.0.2), the alert appears when I load the page (I don't resize the page, just load)

Is here a way for handle the resize window event ONLY ONE TIME when I resize the windows or pass from the portrait to the landscape mode on Smartphone ?

Thanks for help !

**EDIT :**

With this code, I can prevent the Chrome twice fire :

```
var resizeTimer;
window.onresize = function(){
    if (resizeTimer){
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    }
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        alert("FOO");
    }, 50);
};
```

But on Firefox (Android), I keep the same issue. The alert "FOO" is showed when I load the page. (On Smartphone, I want to execute my code only when the user pass from the portrait mode to the landscape mode)

Comment: PS: <script> is best placed **before** the closing `</body>` tag. Not after.

Comment: I just tested , and I have sames issues on Chrome (Desktop) and Firefox (Android)...

Comment: Why the `setTimeout()` If you only want this to appear once then why not set a variable to `false` and change it within your resize eventlistener function?

Comment: @NewToJS : you are right, but this is not the priority. I want to solve the Android issue

Comment: Do you have anything in your `HTML` or `CSS` that alters the elements for mobile devices? If so, could you add an example of some `HTML` and `CSS` to reproduce the problem in a little example/demo? Thank you

Comment: with this simple example, I reproduce the issue (with a private tab from the firefox on smartphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why not have something like this?

```
var CurrentWindowSize = {  w: document.body.clientWidth,  h: document.body.clientHeight }; // only Chrome has correct values here

window.onresize = function(e)
{
  let width  = e.target.outerWidth
  ,   height = e.target.outerHeight
  ;
  if (width != CurrentWindowSize.w
  || height != CurrentWindowSize.h)
  {
    CurrentWindowSize.w = width;
    CurrentWindowSize.h = height;
    WindowIsResized();
  }
}

function WindowIsResized() {
  // your stuff...
}
```